# Bootstrap: show/hide column divs with checkbox and change column span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3.2. I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to show/hide a "col-sz-#" div AND change the "col-sz-#" class in visible divs to resize them to fit the container using checkbox style buttons for each column.

For example, if I start with

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">...</div>
</div>
```

Then if hide 2 of them and the others resize:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 hidden">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 hidden">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">...</div>
</div>
```

if the total columns can't divide 12 evenly like 5, then it wouldn't change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```js
var $myCols =  $("#myColumns");

$("#toggleColumns input").change(function() {
    var index = +this.value - 1;
    var visible = this.checked;

    $($myCols.children().get(index)).toggle(visible);

    resizeColumns();
});

function resizeColumns() {
    var visibleCols = $myCols.children(":visible").length;

    var div = Math.floor(12 / visibleCols);
    var rem = 12 % visibleCols;

    var colSize = (rem === 0) ? div : 2;

    $myCols.children().removeClass().addClass('col-md-'+colSize);

}
```

#### [Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/pgt6tczj/)

**UPDATE**:

If you want to act on multiple identical rows, just find all of them with a selector and call a function on `each` row:

```js
$(".resizeRow").each(function(){
    var $eachRow = $(this);
    // Do Stuff
});
```

#### [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/pgt6tczj/2/)

Comment: This is great. I'm actually trying to target the same class in multiple rows. Like this... [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wqzrxrec/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the issue, I adapted it from https://codepen.io/feger/pen/deIki.

```js
  $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
      var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
      $(column).hide();
  });

  $("input:checkbox").click(function(){
      var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
      $(column).toggle();
  });
```

```css
  .clearfix:before,.clearfix:after {
      content: " ";display: table; /* 2 */}
  .clearfix:after {clear: both;}
  .clearfix {*zoom: 1;}

  .options {margin-bottom: 8px;}

  /* Style checkboxes as Toggle Buttons */
  .ck-button {
      margin:2px;
      background-color:#EFEFEF;
      border-radius:4px;
      border:1px solid #aaa;
      overflow:auto;
      float:left;
      color:#aaa;
  }
  .ck-button:hover {
      background-color:#ddd;
  }
  .ck-button label {
      float:left;
      width:auto;
      margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .ck-button label span {
      text-align:center;
      padding:3px 8px;
      display:block;
  }
  .ck-button label input {
      position:absolute;
      top:-20px;
  }
  .ck-button input:checked + span {
      color:#111;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title></title>
 

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 <div class="options clearfix">
  <div class="ck-button">
   <label><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="first_name" checked="checked"><span>First Name</span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="ck-button">
   <label><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="last_name" checked="checked"><span>Last Name</span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="ck-button">
   <label><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="email"><span>Email</span></label>
  </div>
 </div>

  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th class="first_name">First Name</th>
     <th class="last_name">Last Name</th>
     <th class="email">Email</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="first_name">Larry</td>
      <td class="last_name">Hughes</td>
      <td class="email">larry@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="first_name">Mike</td>
      <td class="last_name">Tyson</td>
      <td class="email">mike@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dmonad/rL0mh32s/2/). Here, I used [jquery toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to show/hide the elements. I think, the fiddle will be a good starting point for you. You can also do this with css (without jquery). Then, you have to set
the `display: none` property.

Comment: This really doesn't explain how to solve the problem, which is far more complex then just calling `toggle` on an element.

Comment: No?, Maybe I should have explained it in more detail. Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/dmonad/rL0mh32s/2/

Comment: The fiddle does, but that should be your answer then. Just pointing to a tool that can solve one part of an issue isn't that helpful. Of your fiddle's 24 lines only two are `toggle()`. You should update your answer to include the full fiddle as it's actually really useful.